# Text vertical position majuscule height baseline

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I want to get my text vertical align middle based on majuscule height, so that I can set one padding for all sides. Someone a idea?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Not possible (or practical) with CSS.

Comment: @Paulie_D probably, yesterday still being investigated

Answer (score -1):

You can vertical align your text using the css property line-height.https://jsfiddle.net/nttct2cj/

**CSS**

```
.div {
   line-height:50px;
   border:1px solid black;
   display:inline-block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="div">
MY TEXT
</div>
```